# How do I leave a team?

Tags: support, status-completed, old-teams

Perhaps it is because I am the team creator of the only team I am on, but I don't see any option for leaving a team.  Is there a way?

And if the reason I can't leave my current team is because I am the creator, is there a way to move that responsibility to a different team member without deleting the team?

The only option I see is deleting the team.

Comment: Click on "members" on the left in the team, then the (X) at the top right of your profile pic in the member listing... it might work - not sure if it should do so though :p

Comment: ... so, can anyone remove anyone?  Or is this a special privilege I have as the team creator?

Comment: Right now, anyone can remove anyone. This may change later; if you'd like to see full-blown hierarchical ACLs, post a feature-request.

Comment: Well, that's why it's a beta I guess.  It's really concerning that all anyone needs to join the team is a special url... and it's this easy to remove all the other users or delete the team...

Comment: @nhgrif These are things we're not unaware of, they're high on our list to address. We want to see how the beta plays out a bit before pitching a few solutions though - don't hesitate to keep pumping out feedback though!

Comment: You never leave a team.. your heart remains there forever.

Comment: I believe you have no negotiating rights for the first year and then you become a free-agent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_agent#National_Football_League_usage

Comment: There is no I in team, there is an 'l' in 'leave' though, which kinda looks the same.

Comment: @MeanGreen I lolled. It's like when people use a lowercase `'l'` suffix to quality a `long` and it looks like: `long foo = 1010l`

Answer (score -1):

The option to change your Role and to leave the Team now shows on your profile every time you access the Team page. Just click the gear icon, and you can leave the Team:

[image: click the gear icon to change your role or leave the Team]

---

Note that the *last member* of a Team can't leave the Team. You can always delete the Team in that case.

Comment: Maybe you should improve the error message. When I try to remove the last member, the current message is white text on gray background with message "unable to remove this member: Access denied".